# Testing if client can connect to WebSockets with port 80, 443, 843

Tags: node.js, websocket, firewall

I'm running a WebSockets application on a node server. Everything works fine, except that my application is used in schools, and some of their firewalls apparently block WebSockets on port 80. I read that some ports like 843 are usually unblocked, but I want to test this before making any switch.

How to test for open WebSockets ports? e.g. try ports 80, 443 & 843 from the client-side and report which ones work? Any tutorials or code snippets would be great...

Comment: well one solution is to keep track of what port the client is trying to connect, and the if an errors occurs then switch port and try another port, what modules are you using?

Comment: I'm ready to use any module really, just want to run this as an experiment for a couple of days/weeks and get the data. I'm actually looking for a tutorial or code snippet where something similar has been  done.

Comment: To maximize the chances of WebSocket being successful, I'd recommend using secure WebSocket (TLS) on standard port 443 with a valid server certificate that is acceptable to browsers without any user interaction. You can try https://demo.crossbar.io/ from one of the school's PCs ..

Comment: @oberstet Thanks for the suggestion, I will try it out on 443 with cert. Unfortunately I do not have access to the schools, they are in different countries. Thats why I need to test it out before I deploy, otherwise it may break for existing users.

Comment: How about using socket.io?  It handles a lot of this sort of stuff, and is widely used.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been using http://websocketstest.com/ to see blocking of my socket.io websockets. I just now came across a scenario too where a client had a firewall blocking traffic on port 80. Rather than insisting on them jumping through hoops I am now listen on 443, not necessary to use SSL either on that port for this purpose.

In nginx I am first redirecting all traffic to socket.test.com port 80 to port 443 thus:

```
server {
    listen              80;
    server_name             socket.test.com;
    rewrite             ^ http://test.com:443$request_uri?;
 }
```

then

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name  socket.test.com

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3004;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

On port 3004 a socket.io server is accepting connections. Works!

2018 update: thanks to letsencrypt.com it's now trivial to add https certs so all this can be done with encryption on 443

Comment: Thanks, this helped, and the application works for a majority of users. But there are still some for which it remains blocked.

Comment: Did you check the debug log? If you figure out what's what, please let me know I am developing an app that I hope works on >99% of mobile browsers.